# I want to modify this python script to output the modification date of the parsed file along with its title

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

So the last programmer left me with this script, that grabs all the old content and writes it all out as a "partial' file.. which strips out all the container html and leaves just the html of the article itself. It then writes a manifest as JSON which gives the url, the title and the date created of all files.

I'd like it to order all the files by the date created, in the manifest, and in the filenames created. (something like [unix-create-date]-[url].partial]). Then I can use the manifest file to list the file in the order they were created, and use the file names themselves as well.

I don't know python, so I don't know how to get the file modification date in there. Thanks for any responses!

Here is the full script.

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import simplejson as json

def parse_article(root, filename):
    path = os.path.join(root, filename)
    abs_path = os.path.abspath(path)
    try:
        article = open(abs_path, 'rU')
        html = article.read()
        article.close()
    except IOError:
        print "Cannot open article: %s" % path

    url = "/%s" % path
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

    title = None
    fallbacks = ['h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'title']
    for fallback in fallbacks:
        if title is None:
            title = soup.find(fallback)
        else:
            break

    content = u"" if soup.body is None else soup.body.renderContents()
    save_file(root, "%s.partial" % filename, content)

    title = u"" if title is None else title.renderContents()
    return unicode(url), title

def process_folder(path):
    files = os.listdir(path)
    articles = filter(lambda name: not name.startswith('index.') and (name.endswith('.html') or name.endswith('.htm')), files)
    manifest = {}

    for article in articles:
        url, title = parse_article(path, article)
        manifest[url] = title

    return manifest

def save_json(root, name, obj):
    if len(obj.keys()) == 0:
        return

    path = os.path.join(root, name)
    manifest = open(path, 'w')
    json.dump(obj, manifest)
    manifest.close()
    print "Wrote %s" % path

def save_file(root, name, content):
    path = os.path.join(root, name)
    manifest = open(path, 'w')
    manifest.write(content)
    manifest.close()
    print "Wrote %s" % path

def process(root):
    root = os.path.abspath(root)
    root_re = '^%s[/]*' % root
    for dirname, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
        dirname = re.sub(root_re, '', dirname)
        if len(dirname) > 0:
            manifest = process_folder(dirname)
            abs_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, dirname))
            save_json(abs_path, "manifest.json", manifest)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    process('.')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the modification date of a file by using [`os.stat`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.stat):

```
>>> import os, time
>>> result = os.stat("/tmp/z.py")
>>> result
posix.stat_result(st_mode=33188, st_ino=6034492, st_dev=16777220L, st_nlink=1, st_uid=501, st_gid=0, st_size=189, st_atime=1424735724, st_mtime=1424735651, st_ctime=1424735651)
>>> print "Modification date: %s -> %s" % (result.st_mtime, time.ctime(result.st_mtime))
Modification date: 1424735651.0 -> Mon Feb 23 15:54:11 2015
>>> print "Creation date: %s -> %s" % (result.st_ctime, time.ctime(result.st_ctime))
Creation date: 1424735651.0 -> Mon Feb 23 15:54:11 2015
>>> print "Access date: %s -> %s" % (result.st_atime, time.ctime(result.st_atime))
Access date: 1424735724.0 -> Mon Feb 23 15:55:24 2015
```

So in your code, you'd probably want to store it in the manifest around here:

```
    ...
    for article in articles:
        url, title = parse_article(path, article)
        manifest[url] = title
        manifest[ctime] = os.stat(path).st_ctime
    ...
```

With that information you can then sort the files based on `ctime`, or convert it to a `datetime` object, etc.